# javafx resize the components and their positions

Tags: image, javafx, resize, screen

I'm searching for how to resize the columns (red and white) and keep their position at the board when I resize the window .

#### correct

[image]

#### the problem

[image]

The architecture of code and binding of columns over the board.

```
//the points of columns in the board map
private int[][] whitepoints={{54,27},{235,27},{417,27}};
private int[][] redpoints={{145,27},{325,27},{507,27}};

StartBoard(Stage primaryStage){

    board.fitWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
    board.fitHeightProperty().bind(primaryStage.heightProperty());
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){

        whiteArray[i]= new ImageView(white);
        whiteArray[i].setLayoutX(whitepoints[i][0]);
        whiteArray[i].setLayoutY(whitepoints[i][1]);
        
        redArray[i]= new ImageView(red);
        redArray[i].setLayoutX(redpoints[i][0]);
        redArray[i].setLayoutY(redpoints[i][1]);
            
    }

}
```

The Start method code

```
Pane root = new Pane();
 
Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

Scene scene = new
Scene(root,screenBounds.getWidth(),screenBounds.getHeight());

primaryStage.setTitle("Backgammon");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
//primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
//primaryStage.setResizable(false);
primaryStage.show();
```

The comments are the alternative way to prevent the user for can resize the window.

Αny proposal for other techniques is desirable because I know that this isn't the right way.

Comment: It looks as if you are setting images on a certain part of the screen, as opposed to on the board. Also, why have separate lines and board images? It seems like you have the lines laid out on the board already, why not just fill them in?

Comment: because i want each column to separated , otherwise how i will can to locate the pawns position ? I'm thinking of to make it with collision to check the position of every pawn. like this  http://prnt.sc/ct919i for using each column like array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `GridPane` to position the triangles.

```
private static Node createTriangle(boolean up, boolean red) {
    final double height = 100d;
    final double width = 40d;
    Polygon result = up ? new Polygon(
            0d, height,
            width / 2, 0d,
            width, height
    ) : new Polygon(
            0d, 0d,
            width / 2, height,
            width, 0d);

    result.setFill(red ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
    return result;
}

private static GridPane generateBoard() {
    GridPane board = new GridPane();

    ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    columnConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    columnConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);

    RowConstraints rowConstraintsTop = new RowConstraints();
    rowConstraintsTop.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    rowConstraintsTop.setValignment(VPos.TOP);

    RowConstraints rowConstraintsBottom = new RowConstraints();
    rowConstraintsBottom.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    rowConstraintsBottom.setValignment(VPos.BOTTOM);

    board.getColumnConstraints().addAll(Stream.generate(() -> columnConstraints).limit(6).toArray(ColumnConstraints[]::new));
    board.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowConstraintsTop, rowConstraintsBottom);

    board.addRow(0, IntStream.range(0, 6).mapToObj(i -> createTriangle(false, (i & 1) != 0)).toArray(Node[]::new));
    board.addRow(1, IntStream.range(0, 6).mapToObj(i -> createTriangle(true, (i & 1) == 0)).toArray(Node[]::new));

    board.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #444;");
    return board;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane board1 = generateBoard(), board2 = generateBoard();
    HBox.setHgrow(board1, Priority.ALWAYS);
    HBox.setHgrow(board2, Priority.ALWAYS);
    HBox root = new HBox(20, board1, board2);
    root.setFillHeight(true);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: brown;");

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```